# How to correctly change state of a multiple nested array of objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

What would be the best way to change the state of multiple nested arrays of objects in React? Let's see the example below: I have a component that will display the top playlist for each genre. I have a property **genre** which is an array of objects and each object has a property **songs** which is also an array of objects. If I want to change the song named Soldier of Fortune to Child in Time (Let's suppose in Change function as parameters I have indexes of Song and Genre already provided from the UI change). How can I access multiple levels of nested objects and not mutate the state?

```
this.state = {
    title: 'Top playlists',
    genres: [
      {
        genreName: 'pop',
        followers: 2456,
        songs: [
          {
            title: 'Soldier of fortune',
            author: 'Deep Purple',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

handleChangeSongName = (e, genreIndex, songIndex) => {
    // genreIndex = 0;
    // songIndex = 0;
    // e.target.name = title;
    // e.target.value = "Child in time"  
    ...What to do here?
  }
```

Comment: This may be vague, but how about instead of using map ( I assumed u used map :D ) use a for loop or a while in which you can store the index of you'r array's as a component propriety ?

Comment: I am just curious about updating the state, not displaying the data. Let's suppose I have displayed everything and I have an input field where you have the list of the data and I got the correct index of song and index of the genre. I just need to figure out how to properly change the state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can modify your handleChangeSongName function to this:

```
  handleChangeSongName = (e, genreIndex, songIndex) => {
// genreIndex = 0;
// songIndex = 0;
// e.target.name = title;
// e.target.value = "Child in time"  
this.setState((prevState) => {
  let temp = {
    ...prevState,
    genres: [...prevState.genres]
  }

  // change title "Soldier of fortune" to "Child in time"
  temp.genres[genreIndex].songs[songIndex][e.target.name] = e.target.value

  return temp
})
```

}

Comment: This kinda works, but I am losing Focus after I type a single letter in the input field. So, I need to click again and type one more letter, and so on

Comment: It is a good practice to update those changes on button press. not when changing value on textInput. do a separate handling of your textInput.

Comment: Also can I know what component did you use for the input and how you implemented it?

Comment: I used Input from the 'reactstrap' module. 
I am mapping the array of the elements and then onChange, I am sending an event, what genre is and what song I am changing. Something like this. 
<Input value={songs[songIndex].title} onChange={(e) => {handleChange(e, genreIndex, songIndex, )}} />

Comment: Mine is working on simple TextInput component of react-native.I think you implement it right , but i dont know the cause of sudden unfocus while you triggering a key.  But in my answer on your main question. that is one of the best way to change to state of a nested objects.

Comment: I will try to figure it out...However, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194142/discussion-between-amel-amce-muminovic-and-mervzs).

Answer (score 0):

I would change your state like this:

```
this.state = {
      title: "Top playlists",
      genres: [
        {
          followers: 2456,
          genreName: "pop",
          songs: [
            {
              title: "Soldier of fortune",
              author: "Deep Purple"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

and then

```
handleChangeSongName = (e, genreIndex, songIndex) => {
    // genreIndex = 0;
    // songIndex = 0;
    // e.target.name = title;
    // e.target.value = "Child in time"  
    ...What to do here?

    const genres = _.cloneDeep(this.state.genres); // create deep copy with underscore
    // or like this
    // const genres = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.genres))

    if(genres.length && genres[genreIndex] && genres[genreIndex].songs.length && genres[genreIndex].songs[songIndex]) {
        genres[genreIndex].songs[songIndex][e.target.name] = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            genres: genres
        });
     }

  }
```

Comment: I think this will mutate the state cause I am directly working on its values?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You should create a deep copy of genres, and than manipulating before set a new state. I updated the answer.